# Sending a StringIO to a Twisted FileSender

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to send some image data to a FileSender in Twisted. All works fine if I use a temporary file to save the image;

```
#works
img = Image(format='png', blob=base64.decodestring(dt))
img.save(filename='/tmp/tmp.png')
file = open('/tmp/tmp.png','rb')
filesender = FileSender().beginFileTransfer(file, request)

def fileFinished(ignored):
 request.finish()

filesender.addCallback(fileFinished)
```

However what I would like to do is do this in memory rather than to a file. I have tried to use a StringIO to do this, but the FileSender seems to only send a few bytes before giving up. What am I doing wrong?

```
img = Image(format='png', blob=base64.decodestring(dt))
buffer = StringIO()
img.save(buffer)
filesender = FileSender().beginFileTransfer(buffer, request)

def fileFinished(ignored):
 request.finish()

filesender.addCallback(fileFinished)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `StringIO` is positioned at EOF when you try to send it.  It's surprising it sends even a few bytes (I suspect it doesn't and you're just seeing HTTP framing).  Try seeking to the beginning before you call `beginFileTransfer`.

Also, you don't really need to use `FileSender` here.  Your data is already entirely in memory.  `FileSender` may actually increase the cost of sending it.  Instead, you might consider the simpler:

```
request.write(buffer.getvalue())
request.finish()
```